# Java Memory exceeding 512mb despite having set -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:MetaspaceSize=100M?

Tags: java, heroku, jvm

I have deployed a java application to Heroku using the following vm options:

```
-Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:MetaspaceSize=100M
```

Despite this, my application consistently gets **Error R14 (Memory Quota Exceeded)** errors from Heroku.  This is because the **memory footprint reaches 540+mb** (and the quota is 512mb).

How can a java application take up over 500mb, when I'm only allocating 400mb to it in the VM args?  Am I missing a VM arg?

I would expect the JVM to OOM before reaching 512mb of memory (but it just increases beyond the limits I have set it).

Perhaps I've completely misunderstood how those VM args work?

Any help on this would be hugely appreciated.

Notes:

- i'm using java 8
- my procfile is as follows:

  ```
  web: java -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:MetaspaceSize=100M -javaagent:./lib/heroku-javaagent-2.0.jar=stdout=true,lxmem=true -Dserver.port=$PORT -Dspring.profiles.active=heroku -cp ./app.jar          org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
  ```

The java agent above spits out the following details in the logs:

```
Dec 13 11:45:54 app/web.1:  measure.mem.jvm.heap.used=177M measure.mem.jvm.heap.committed=212M measure.mem.jvm.heap.max=273M 
Dec 13 11:45:54 app/web.1:  measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=129M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.committed=132M measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.max=0M 
Dec 13 11:45:54 app/web.1:  measure.mem.jvm.direct.used=0M measure.mem.jvm.direct.count=0 measure.mem.jvm.direct.capacity=74M 
Dec 13 11:45:54 app/web.1:  measure.mem.jvm.mapped.used=0M measure.mem.jvm.mapped.count=0 measure.mem.jvm.mapped.capacity=0M 
Dec 13 11:45:54 app/web.1:  measure.mem.linux.vsz=5817M measure.mem.linux.rss=543M
```

Comment: There could be memory leaks in your application itself, you can deploy your application in local and see the memory allocation behavior in visualVM or Jconsole.

Comment: hi @kakurala .  If there was a memory leak, wouldn't the JVM OOM, rather than just increase beyond its limits?

Comment: Yes, I assume this error is coming while you are starting the app, not after sometime. If so then while starting itself your app taking more than allocated space and eventually failing. To confirm deploy it in your local PC and then see if same error being thrown or not. This will tell you whether the issue is with Heroku or app itself.

Comment: The key here is `measure.mem.jvm.nonheap.used=129M`, which means there is 129MB of off-heap memory being used, that doesn't care about heap limits. Off heap memory can be used by direct `ByteBuffers`, memory mapped files and such. Does heroku consider the quota to include the memory that the JVM is using in addition to the application, or just the application?

Comment: There are a lot more things that may use memory besides Java Heap and Metaspace: Code Cache, Direct ByteBuffers, Thread stacks, native libraries...

Comment: I thought code cache is now stored in Metaspace, which I am limiting? And I'm also limiting the thread stack size with -Xss512k. I hadn't considered ByteBuffers and native libraries though. Thanks for that. I guess there's no way to know what that will be?

Comment: @Kayaman - heroku seems to measure the RSS (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resident_set_size) which is the total memory used by a process

Comment: @kakurala - the error comes after the app has been running for a few hours. The error definitely comes from heroku, not from the app. The error means that my process is using up too much space (beyond its quota of 512mb). Sorry for not explaining that better

Comment: Code Cache and Metaspace are completely different areas. -Xss is a per-thread limit, i.e. more threads => more memory. Use [Native Memory Tracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html) to get the detailed report about JVM memory usage (but still excluding memory-mapped files and native libraries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can a java application take up over 500mb, when I'm only allocating 400mb to it in the VM args? Am I missing a VM arg?

The JVM has many categories of memory include heap, metaspace, thread stacks, code cache, and more. There can even be memory allocated via JNI that the JVM cannot account for. Have a look at [this blog post on JVM memory](http://jkutner.github.io/2017/04/28/oh-the-places-your-java-memory-goes.html).

> I would expect the JVM to OOM before reaching 512mb of memory (but it just increases beyond the limits I have set it).

Most OOM errors only happen when you run out of heap space. In your case, you have enough heap space, but all those other categories are adding up and running you over the 512mb limit.

You can try lowering `Xmx` to `-Xmx256m`. Any lower than that and you probably will start getting OOM errors.

You might also want to inspect your code for leaking IO buffers. If not closed properly, they can sometimes cause native memory (off-heap) leaks. Finally, check if any of your dependencies (third-party libraries) are using JNI or allocating native memory.

Answer (score 3):

```
-Xmx256m -XX:+UseContainerSupport
```

did it for me. Using Heroku defaults (ie -Xmx300m) exceeded the 512MB threshold of the Dyno.